# How to retrieve the contents of page created in admin panel in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

> I have the necessity to create a template and use it in the admin
>   panel page but I want to use the custom field data provided in the
>   admin panel and want to keep the template blank. This is because I
>   have to check a condition for a specific page by `is_page_template()`
>   function for which it is necessary to create a template. Tell me how
>   could I retrieve the custom fields data in the template or is there
>   any way through which I can use template but actually use the admin
>   page data.Please answer soon...........

Answer (score -1):

```
query_posts('post_type' => 'post'); 
while(have_posts()):
    the_post();
    /* Add your code here */
endwhile;
```

Comment: Through this we get the details from content written in wordpress backend in a custom page template.

Comment: You really shouldn't ever use `query_posts`. It's better to use `get_posts()` or use a new `WP_Query` object.

Comment: `get_posts()` does not work for custom page template. I am a wordpress starter and I commonly use `query_posts()` to display all the  post or page content. Why are you prefer `WP_Query` objects

Comment: `get_posts()` *does* work for custom page templates and post types. [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) even outlines why you shouldn't use `query_posts()`:  `"This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. There are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances. Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods."`